# How to populate 2nd Procedure variables from 1st Procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hello I can't figure out how to put values in the 2nd procedure from the join at the top of the first procedure. I did test it with "CALL Procedure2('value','value')" and it worked great fyi,just stuck on making it usable now. Thanks Any help would be great. 
   I don't mind not including it the 2nd procedure here, but that arises the question of how to put Left JOINS in an if else statement. If I can get this to work would be wonderful.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Procedure1`()
BEGIN

DECLARE Proc1ValueA INT;
DECLARE Proc1ValueB VarChar(40);

UPDATE table4
LEFT JOIN `table1` ON `table1`.`var1` = `table4`.`var1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`var2` = `table4`.`var2`
LEFT JOIN `table3` ON `table3`.`var3` = `table4`.`var3`

SET 
table1.var6 = table3.var8,
table2.var2 = table1.var2,
table3.var1 = table2.var5;

SET table1.var2 = @Proc1ValueA;
SET table2.var3 = @Proc1ValueB;

CALL Procedure2(@Proc1ValueA,@Proc1ValueB);
END
```

Edit:
Here are some tables of the structure for the Joins I am trying to achieve in procedure2:

```
Table 1
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | Table2FK | ValueA |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |       12 | var5   |
+----+----------+--------+

Table 2
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | Table3FK | ValueB |
+----+----------+--------+
| 12 |       8  | var2   |
+----+----------+--------+

Table 3 - ValueC is a unique index
+----+---------+
| ID | ValueC |
+----+---------+
|  8 | var3    |
+----+---------+

Table 4 (source of data)
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueD | ValueE |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | var4   | var5   |
+----+--------+--------+


CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure2(in vartable1 INT(12), vartable4 INT(8),    
vartable3 INT, vartable2 INT)
Begin

IF EXISTS (select table3.ID from table3 where table3.ValueC = vartable4) 
THEN
    UPDATE table2 SET table2.table3FK = (select table3.ID from table3 
where table3.ValueC = vartable4)  WHERE table2.ID = vartable2;      
END IF;

IF EXISTS (select table3.ID from table3 where table3.ValueC = vartable4) 
THEN
    DELETE FROM table3 WHERE table3.ID = vartable3;
ELSE 
    UPDATE table3 SET table3.ValueC = vartable4 WHERE table3.ID = 
vartable3;
END IF;
END$$
```

I included some more variables in the beginning in case I needed them.

Comment: hi @newpie, you are doing an update-join transaction. does this mean that you also have to call Procedure2 per iteration? Is the # of updates equivalent to the # of Procedure2 calls?

Comment: Hello thanks for responding I believe I can do this without doing each iteration.  As I am new to procedures I am having trouble preforming my Left Joins in Procedure2, so I tried this method (combining with procedure1) and it works when I put my own variables in, but not the above. If you like I can post an example of my Procedure2 IF Else statement down below that I am having issues with joins. Just let me know, thanks.